# Edit DataGridView via Designer in inherited UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I created a UserControl with a Button, a TextBox and a DataGridView.
I set the modifiers of all controls to public.

Now If I inherit from that UserControl, I can modify the TextBox and the Button via Designer (move around, change properties) just as I expected. But for the DataGridView all properties are disabled.

Is there any reason, why I can't modify a DataGridView via the Designer in an inherited UserControl?

Comment: Indeed, that's a strange one.  Looking at the designer-created code behind the parent user-control, I can see nothing which locks the grid.  Yet, when I inherit from it & use the visual editor, the control shows with a little lock at the top, indicating that something has locked the control.  I see no reason for it to be locked, however, although something must be doing so.  Sounds like a question for the designer of the DataGridView control.

Comment: fixed that. Look at my solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution here: http://adamhouldsworth.blogspot.com/2010/02/winforms-visual-inheritance-limitations.html

In short:

1. Add a reference to System.Design
2. Inherit from DataGridView with this code:

   ```
   [Designer(typeof(ControlDesigner))]
   public class InheritableDataGridView : DataGridView
   {
       public InheritableDataGridView()
           : base()
       { }
   }
   ```
3. ???
4. Profit!!!

Comment: One thing to note:  In my specific case at least (I'm using VS2008), the little lock in the corner of the control does still appear, however the properties in the designer are editable.  This confused me at first, as I thought the solution didn't work.  Thanks!